# Unable to download docx file using C#

Tags: c#, download, docx

This is my code and I am trying since hours to download the docx file. but no success.
Where I might be lagging, need a slight hint.

```
if (File.Exists(sTempPath + sCreateFileName))
            {
                FileInfo file =new FileInfo(sTempPath + sCreateFileName);
                Response.ClearContent();
                // LINE1: Add the file name and attachment, which will force the open/cancel/save dialog to show, to the header
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
                // Add the file size into the response header
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
                // Set the ContentType                        
                Response.ContentType = ReturnExtension(file.Extension.ToLower());
                // Write the file into the response (TransmitFile is for ASP.NET 2.0. In ASP.NET 1.1 you have to use WriteFile instead)
                Response.TransmitFile(sTempPath + sCreateFileName);
                // End the response
                HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
            }
```

and Return content type gives, content type for docx file:

```
"application/ms-word"
```

where if sTempPath+sCreateFileName is the whole path of the file.

**Update:**
I tried content type:

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
```

This is not working.

Comment: try with content type as `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`

Comment: There is no error but file is not downloading.

Comment: @ Damith: I have tried this but no success.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The correct MIME type for DOCX is not `application/msword` but `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`.

The MIME type you specified is for DOC files.

Also you might want to put a `Response.Flush()` and a `Response.End()` instead of the `CompleteRequest()`.

Comment: Iti, I have modified my reply.

Comment: This works, infact the previous code works but not in button click, but on page load. I am not getting why this is happening?

Comment: It is probably because ASP.NET does not transmit the entire file if part of the output is still in its Response buffer. That is why you need to flush the buffer and tell ASP.NET to end the Response.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code

```
 string FileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/physical folder"), attFileName);
            System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
            response.ClearContent();
            response.Clear();

     Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename = \"{0}\"", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileName)));
            response.TransmitFile(FileName);
            response.Flush();
            response.End();
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. For me it works:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
{
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
    memStream.SetLength(fileStream.Length);
    fileStream.Read(memStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)fileStream.Length);

    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=myfile.docx");
    Response.BinaryWrite(memStream.ToArray());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.Close();
    Response.End();
}
```